# ASP.net User credential disclose

Tags: asp.net

I create a simple login form using ASP.Net Web Form. The web form only have 2 text boxes and one button. The two text boxes are for user id and password.
When I click button, it will redirect to other page. At the same time, when i open browser developer tools (F12 Chrome), i will see my user credential. How to prevent this to disclose? Please refer to image below.

[Developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBayk.png)

Comment: Not sure what your question is here. Are you concerned about sending a password in the clear when the form is submitted? That's what a secure protocol like `https` is for.

Comment: Are you redirecting after login authentication or just redirecting ?

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: Can i send the user credential in hash/encrypted mode?

Comment: @Sami: Yes, will check user id and password first before redirect.

Comment: Use hashing or WebMethod to verify credentials, call webMethod with jQuery and if authenticated move to next page.